# How to evaluate a list into its normal form with a good running speed?

Tags: haskell

I am working with an implement of SHA-1, using Haskell. However, I got into trouble with `seq`, which slows down the speed of the following code.

The following code is simplified but still able to show my problem. (The code about IO actions is reserved, because only the large data makes efforts)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Word
import Data.List
import Data.Bits
import System.IO
import Text.Printf

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let filePath2 = "/path/to/a/large/file"
  content <- L.readFile filePath2
  print $ sha1Run content

type ByteSeq = [Word8]
type HsPair = (ByteSeq, ByteSeq, ByteSeq, ByteSeq, ByteSeq)

data ChunkContext = ChunkContext !Int !Int !B.ByteString !HsPair
  deriving Show

initHs :: HsPair                      -- some initial values, normal form
initHs = let
  h0 = [0x67, 0x45, 0x23, 0x01]
  h1 = [0xef, 0xcd, 0xab, 0x89]
  h2 = [0x98, 0xba, 0xdc, 0xfe]
  h3 = [0x10, 0x32, 0x54, 0x76]
  h4 = [0xc3, 0xd2, 0xe1, 0xf0]
  in (h0, h1, h2, h3, h4)

seqList :: [a] -> [a]
seqList xs = foldr ((.) . seq) id xs xs

sha1Run :: L.ByteString -> ChunkContext
sha1Run = L.foldlChunks chunkRoll initCtx
  where
    initCtx =  ChunkContext 0 0 B.empty initHs

-- Something needed to ensure just 512 bits are passed into chunkUpdate
chunkRoll :: ChunkContext -> B.ByteString -> ChunkContext
chunkRoll ctx@(ChunkContext accuSize restSize rest hs) chunk
  | B.null chunk = ctx
  | sizeTaken < sizeToTake = ChunkContext 0 0 (rest <> m) hs
  | sizeTaken >= sizeToTake = chunkRoll (ChunkContext 0 0 B.empty (chunkUpdate hs chunkData)) ms
  where
    chunkData = B.unpack chunk
    !sizeToTake = 64 - restSize
    !sizeTaken = B.length m
    (!m, !ms) = B.splitAt sizeToTake chunk

chunkUpdate :: HsPair -> ByteSeq -> HsPair
chunkUpdate hs bs = foldl' step hs [0..79] -- iteration for 80 times
  where
    step zh i = roundUpdate cz zh
    chunkData = bs
    cz = take 13 chunkData

-- really simple function
roundUpdate :: ByteSeq -> HsPair -> HsPair
roundUpdate wt hs@(a, b, c, d, e) = (na, nb, nc, nd, ne)
  where
    !na = seqList $ a
    !nb = seqList $ b
    !nc = seqList $ c
    !nd = seqList $ d
    !ne = seqList $ e
```

The key is `seqList`! I try to apply `seqList` to a list to limit the expanding "thunk". *When there is no `seqList` and some extra operation for lists in the function `roundUpdate`, the program would quickly eat so much memory that I have to force to stop the process.* `seq` is needed, in my view.

But this program *runs really slowly when `seqList` added*, especially `filePath2` is a "large" file (about 1MB), though the constant menory is allocated.

A profiling report has been generated by `ghc -prof`, following [this guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html).

The amazing `seqList`!

```
COST CENTRE MODULE    SRC                    %time %alloc

seqList     Main      lab.hs:39:1-39          93.3   97.3
chunkUpdate Main      lab.hs:(58,1)-(62,26)    2.8    1.6
roundUpdate Main      lab.hs:(65,1)-(71,21)    1.6    1.0
```

How solve the performance problem in the code above? How to design the function `seqList` for the reasonable memory usage and executing speed.

Comment: See [How to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This snippet isn't complete and almost certainly isn't minimal. Minimizing is a critical step in any debugging effort; even if it weren't required for a good question, you should still do it.

Comment: There is too much going on here for me to see, but in your "Maybe not important" section you are using a lot of expensive functions: `reverse` and `(!!)` are both usually indicators that you need better data structures.  But I agree with Daniel, we need to be able to tinker with it, post an MCVE.